# How to create 3D surface with skeletonized images?

Tags: opencv, 3d, vtk, surface

I'm using OpenCV 3.1 (with VTK7.1) and attempt to create 3D-like surface with 2D images.

The idea is simple:

1. input continuous image(each frame of video stream)
2. skeletonization processing each frame.
3. stacking in 3-dimension space. Here is the problem:
   **How can I convert a image to point cloud and how can I display?**

Here is a part of the code:

```
for (;;)
{
    inStream >> singleFrm;

    if (singleFrm.empty()) {
        break;
    }
    else {

        imshow("Origin", singleFrm);
        singleFrm = singleFrm(roi);
        cvtColor(singleFrm, roiSkelFrm, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        const Size2d size(roiSkelFrm.cols, roiSkelFrm.rows);            

        threshold(roiSkelFrm, roiSkelFrm, 80, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
        thinning(roiSkelFrm, roiSkelFrm);

        stackChFrm[0] = roiSkelFrm;
        stackChFrm[1] = roiSkelFrm;
        stackChFrm[2] = roiSkelFrm;

        cv::merge(stackChFrm, 3, skelFrm);
        skelFrm.convertTo(skelFrm, CV_32FC3);           

        viz::WCloud aCloudSlice(skelFrm, viz::Color::white());          
        myWindow.showWidget("image", aSlice);

        myWindow.spinOnce(1, true);

        if (waitKey(1) == 27)
            break;
    }
}

while (!myWindow.wasStopped())
{
    myWindow.spinOnce(1, true);
}
```

Comment: should be similar to "marching cubes" algorithm

Comment: should be easier: if you know or assume the 3D width and height of a pixel and the depth of an image (in your stack) you can convert the images directly: image_s (x,y ) becomes 3D point (x × width, y × height, s × depth) with s the stack level of the image.